# Как сделать стандартный интерфейс яндекс-карты?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, карты, яндекс-карты

Вот отличный рабочий код кластериализации меток яндекс:

```
ymaps.ready([
  'Map', 'Placemark', 'Clusterer', 'ClusterPlacemark'
]).then(function() {
  var map = new ymaps.Map('map', {
    center: [55.75, 37.62], zoom: 9, controls: []
  });
  var placemarks = [
    new ymaps.Placemark([55.75, 37.62]),
    new ymaps.Placemark([55.75, 37.52]),
    new ymaps.Placemark([55.75, 37.72]),
  ];

  var clusterer = createVisitedClusterer({
    // Опции кластеризатора.
    clusterIconColor: 'black'
  }, {
    // Опции "посещенных" кластеров.
    iconColor: 'red'
  });
  clusterer.add(placemarks);

  map.geoObjects.add(clusterer);
}).catch(console.error);

function createVisitedClusterer(options, visitedClusterOptions) {
  // Создаем кластеризатор.
  var clusterer = new ymaps.Clusterer(options);

  // Сохраняем старую функцию createCluster с помощью Function.prototype.bind.
  var defaultCreateCluster = clusterer.createCluster.bind(clusterer);

  // Хеш посещенных кластеров.
  var visitedClusters = { /* 'id,id,id': true */ };

  // Переопределяем метод createCluster у кластеризатора.
  clusterer.createCluster = function(center, geoObjects) {
    // Создаем стандартный кластер.
    var cluster = defaultCreateCluste
```

Реализован здесь: http://krk.by/stuff/
Подскажите, как можно сделать, чтобы на карте остались стандартные регулировки зума, линейка и др. Как здесь: http://krk.by/stuff/36-1-0-18

И если не сложно - как можно поменять картинку меток и кластеров на свою?

Answer (score 0):

В вашем коде элементы управления отключены принудительно - **controls: []**.

Подробно об отдельных элементах расписано в [документации](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/dg/concepts/controls/standard.html) API Яндекс.Карт. Также можно включить один из [стандартных наборов](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/dg/concepts/controls/built-in.html), например полноразмерные элементы включаются опцией **controls: ['largeMapDefaultSet']**.

Пример создания кластеров с кастомными иконками также есть в [песочнице](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/clusterer_custom_icon) Яндекса. Для этого используется параметр **clusterIcons**.